# How to show 2 or 3 slides per page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic2

I'm using [ion-slides](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/)

But how to show 2 or 3 slides per page? Only 1 by default. Thank you.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you want? Maybe this can help http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#slides

Comment: It doesn't help me. Need 2 or 3 slides per page like this https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/stylish.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend yout to look at http://www.idangero.us/swiper/demos, it will help you a lot with slides on Ionic and you can configure it a lot.

For you need you can set `slidesPerView: 3` for example.